# Create SQL statement with mulitple AND

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

I have a problem with creating right SQL request.
This is my table:

```
item    warehouse   amount
item1   A   1
item1   B   5
item2   A   9
item2   B   2
item3   A   1
item3   A   0
item4   B   1
```

I would like to display all items that:

1. -Are in warehouse A in number less than 2
2. -Are in watehouse B in number grater than 0
   At the same time.

I would expect item1 will be displayed.

My code so far is:

```
SELECT item, warehouse  , amount

FROM XXXX

WHERE 
(warehouse  = B AND amount>0)
AND 
(warehouse  = A AND amount<2)
```

I know that warehouse   = B AND warehouse   = A will never happened, but i do not have any idea where to go from here.

I'am new to SQL, but i have feeling that i need to use GRUPBY

Any help ?

Comment: I think you want your WHERE clause to be OR between the 2 sets of criteria.  So WHERE 
(warehouse  = B AND amount>0)
OR
(warehouse  = A AND amount<2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  Use `where` to get *either* condition.  Then check that both are met.  Assuming that there is one row per item per warehouse, you can use:

```
SELECT item
FROM XXXX
WHERE (warehouse = 'B' AND amount > 0) OR
      (warehouse = 'A' AND amount < 2)
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Note that this does not return the amounts.  If you want that as well, then pivot the data using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item,
       SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse = 'B' THEN amount END) as b_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse = 'A' THEN amount END) as a_amount
FROM XXXX
WHERE (warehouse = 'B' AND amount > 0) OR
      (warehouse = 'A' AND amount < 2)
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, there is a lot to learn for me, lucky my Gordon Linoff give me a hand this time !